# How to reorganize some format.js rails 3 controller code into clean jquery .js.erb files

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to reorganize some controller code into .js.erb jquery files. (Warning, this is messy!)

I have this code in my create action:

```
 def create
      # do stuff

 if @adverse_event.save
    format.js{
         template_id =@study.template_id
         @template_adverse_event_columns = AdverseEventColumn.find(:all, :conditions => ["template_id is ? OR study_id is ?", template_id, @study.id])
         @adverse_events = AdverseEvent.find(:all, :conditions=>['study_id=?',@study.id])
         @adverse_event_result = AdverseEventResult.new
      render :update do |page|
          # replace some partials           
      end   
    }
    format.html { redirect_to(@adverse_event, :notice => 'Adverse event was successfully created.') }
    format.xml  { render :xml => @adverse_event, :status => :created, :location => @adverse_event }
else
     problem_html = "Error message"
     format.js{
         render :update do |page| 
              page.replace_html 'adverse_event_validation_message', problem_html
         end
    }         
    format.html { render :action => "new" }
    format.xml  { render :xml => @adverse_event.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
end

 end
```

I'm trying to convert it to jquery so I can do all the div/html replacing, etc in a create.js.erb file. How do I do this with the conditional based on whether it saves? do I need two create.js.erb files, one for format.js if save is successful, and one if not? how would I call them? Am I on the right track, even?

Thanks so much and sorry if this isn't making a lot of sense - feel free to ask me to clarify and I will edit accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A tutorial worth plenty explanations:

http://www.stjhimy.com/posts/7-creating-a-100-ajax-crud-using-rails-3-and-unobtrusive-javascript

Bonus, a second one:

http://blog.bernatfarrero.com/jquery-and-rails-3-mini-tutorial/